# shallow copy and deeply copy in object-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have question about "copy" in objective-c, my function in Car.m is like this:

```
 - (id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
 {
    Car *carCopy;
    carCopy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];

    carCopy.name = self.name;  //not  [name copy]

    return (carCopy);

 } // copyWithZone
```

int the main.m:

```
    Car *car = [[Car alloc] init];
    car.name = @"abc";

    Car *copyCar = [car copy];

    [copyCar print];

    car.name = @"123";

    [copyCar print];
```

for the property name , i think both the car and copyCar point to the same NSString Object so that when I do "car.name = @"123" " , copyCar.name should also be changed. But when i print the copyCar twice as in the code, they both print the name as "abc". I want to know why it is not a shallow copy ?

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1) they may both start out pointing to the same NSString, but when you do `car.name = @"123"`, you are now making `car.name` point someplace else. You are changing the pointer, not the object it points to, and changing the pointer in `car` does not affect the pointer in `copyCar`. If you (hypothetically) did something like `[car.name appendString:@"xxx"]`, *that* would change the object. But, you can't, because

2) `NSString`s are immutable -- you can't change the NSString object once it's been created

Answer (score 0):

You're not mutating the string for the `name` property. You're replacing it outright. Since `car` and `copyCar` are not, in fact, the same object, assigning to `car.name` cannot possibly affect `copyCar.name`.

Answer (score 0):

Both `car` and `copyCar` point to the same string initially, but they both have *different* references to the same string. If you change the reference in one object, it doesn't affect the reference in the other object, so that's how `car` can point to the new string but not the `carCopy`.